# Failure to load CSS and Javascript even after creating the "static" directory and changing the <link> and <script> tags in the HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

Currently trying to learn Flask, and I am trying to route to an HTML file that loads some CSS from a stylesheet and some Javacript from a .js file. The HTML, CSS, and JS files were from a front-end project I had worked on previously, so I initially just copied the files into the directory. When that failed, I did some research and found out that I needed to create a static folder and change the way I linked to the stylesheet and the script. However, that is still not working.

Flask snippet:

```
@app.route('/landing')
def landingPage():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

HTML snippet (index.html):

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles.css') }}">
  <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='app.js') }}" defer> </script>
</head>
```

The root directory contains app.py (the Flask file), the subdirectory templates which contains index.html, and the subdirectory static which contains styles.css and app.js.

In the console, I get an error for failure to load the script with source 127.0.0.1:5000/static/app.js. Interestingly, the file is referred to as landing.html and not index.html, but I don't think this has anything to do with my issue (if i'm wrong please let me know).

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Where is your subdirectory static root folder or in templates folder, it should be in root directory.

Comment: @charchit Yup that turned out to be it. Unfortunately I cannot approve a comment, but Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the static directory must be contained inside the root directory, and not inside the template directory.

```
|-- app.py
|-- templates 
|   `--teamplate.html
`-- static
    |-- css
    |   `-- style.css
    `-- js
        `-- file.css
```

Comment: This is such a dumb oversight on my end I can't believe I've not noticed it. Thank you a lot, answer approved.